# "Inputs are invalid" vs. "Inputs were invalid"

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> Applications send a warning message if the received inputs from the user are invalid.

Is "*are invalid*" correct or should it be "*were invalid*"?

Comment: Why do you think it should be *were*?

Answer (score 3):

It could depend on the rest of the sentence; you need to be careful about matching the tenses between the different clauses.  However, in most cases, either "were invalid" or "are invalid" would be OK.

If I were programming this,

- I would write "are invalid" if the user's inputs are still visible, and the user has the opportunity to change them and submit the inputs a second time;
- I would write "were invalid" for a batch process, or some other
  process in which the user input phase has finished, and the inputs can't be revisited.

I hope this is helpful.  This is one of those cases where different people would handle it in different ways, and there's really no "wrong" answer.

Comment: Well, the sentence sounds like a description from a manual or something like that. In that case I'd always go with *are*.